# Why RabbitMQ giving AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 3,1,0,0 eception?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have integrated RabbitMQ with the spring boot application. when I try to publish a message, getting exceptions like

```
AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 3,1,0,0
```

and

```
An unexpected connection driver error occurred
```

here is my dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency
```

Here i am attaching a full stack trace.[image]

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace? If you cannot, just check the AMQP compatibility from RabbitMQ [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html)

Comment: @Aristotelis Please check I added it.

Comment: Do you by any chance have Apache QPID running?

Comment: @Aristotelis Sorry?  I did not get what you are saying

Comment: It is for messaging built on AMQP. Maybe you can check if the QPID server is running on the same port (5672) as your rabbitmq server. (they use different versions of the protocol). Stop the QPID or change the rabbitmq port